# shortcut or plug-in for typing underscore in android studio other than `shift` + `-`

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, underscore.js

Is there another way to type underscore in android studio other than `shift` + `-` ??
maybe shortcut or a plugin to do so ?
I've already searched but didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

Underscore can be typed anywhere with just <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> key but I think I didn't understand your question exactly because I know that everyone knows <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> types _

Comment: I edited the question , I meant other than `shift` + `-`

Comment: Sorry to ask, but can you please say why you want to do so? So from that we can get the solution easily